# jQuery Tags With Filters Throw Errors

Tags: javascript, jquery

When working on websites, I usually have 1 JavaScript file I use across all my pages, and use functions & hopefully-unique names to distinguish everything. Sometimes, I want to call a function on a DOM element or its ancestors or descendants, and I may want to use a filter. For example, I may use

`var stylesheets = $(".stylesheet").data("css").split(" ");`

If there are any elements with the `stylesheet` class, this variable would store an array representing the `data-css` attribute of all of them (on my page, there happens to be only one). However, when no elements on a page have the class `stylesheet`, Firebug throws an error,

```
TypeError: $(...).data(...) is undefined


var stylesheets = $(".stylesheet").data("css").split(" ");
```

& the rest of the `.js` file does not execute.

I have cases where I would want there to be tags I call a function on, but where the filter I use would not apply to any of them. The most common case is where I use some functions on one page, and others on another page. The filters for the functions would be met on some pages, but not on others, and none of my code would execute. What should I do in this case? I don't want to have unnecessary code like using `if` statements with `.length`, because that would get excessive.

Comment: So you want to call a function on everything *except* some elements?

Comment: Or do you want to introduce a way that some logic only occurs on a specific page?

Comment: Second one. Could be multiple pages, though, obviously.

Comment: You should use a router to delegate your application logic.

Comment: A router? You mean a PHP file that decides what pages the browser should get?

Comment: @tyris No, I mean using a router in JavaScript to separate your application logic.

Comment: Oh, I have never heard of that. I will not be able to do that in the current project, but for the future how would I make one?

Comment: can you explain what error does exactly firebug show ?

Comment: `Type Error: $(...).hide() is undefined.` (in that specific instance)

Comment: @trysis There are enough, just Google a bit.

Comment: Also what is the result of `console.log(jQuery);` ?

Comment: Just updated my question with an actual example. The error is               `TypeError: $(...).data(...) is undefined
var stylesheets = $(".stylesheet").data("css").split(" ");`. The result of `console.log(jQuery);` is `function()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix your selector to actually grab only the items which match your conditions:

```
$(".stylesheets[data-css]").data("css").split(" ");
```

You can [read more about jQuery's selectors here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

EDIT

As your concern here is with the non-existence of the selector, and because `split` is a normal Javascript method and lacks some of the "safety" mechanisms the jQuery methods typically come with when dealing with empty collections, this would probably be the most terse way to go:

```
var cssAttr = $(".stylesheet").data("css");
var stylesheets = (cssAttr) ? cssAttr : null;
```

Note that I've only decided to go to the DOM once here by using the `cssAttr` variable. I would recommend you doing the same here to prevent touching the DOM twice for the same thing.

Now, if you really want to optimize, and you don't intend to have multiple matching selectors (and that does appear to be the case based on your code), you could always skip the jQuery here. You're not really doing anything vanilla JS couldn't already do, jQuery isn't really bringing anything to the table, and you'll benefit from a slightly faster selector here:

```
var cssAttr = document.getElementsByClassName("stylesheet")[0].dataset.css;
var stylesheets = (cssAttr) ? cssAttr : null;
```

Note you'll need to be targeting [IE9 and above](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName) for that selector to work.

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant when there is no element with class `stylesheet` Firebug throws the error. Edited my post.

Comment: I don't think we're worrying about IE anything.

Comment: So you are saying my problem in this case was that `split` is regular JavaScript, not jQuery? So why is the error happening on `.data()` & not `.split`?

Comment: Yep. `data` doesn't have a method `split` because `data` is returning `undefined`, and `split` is a property of a string. Most JS functions have a little check within them to ensure they're being applied against a collection, but normal JS methods obviously lack that.

Comment: It does not even get to the `split()` part before it fails. It fails on the `data()` part.

Comment: Define "fails" for me

Comment: It says `$(...).data(...) is undefined`, which means it is not finding a tag with that `data` attribute (because none exist). If what you said were true, that the problem is with `split`, then it would say `$(...).split(...) is undefined` (or something like that), because that `data` part would execute but not the `split()` part. I'm not really sure how to explain it better than that.

Comment: `data` is returning undefined because the attribute you're looking for either doesn't exist, or the selector doesn't exist. It returns undefined because there's no better string to return. If it were actually an issue with the `data` method, you would be receiving a `method not found` error. I'm not sure what is preventing you from using my solution.

Comment: What is preventing me is I finished that project & I asked thid question for reference for the future. I suppose if I get a chance with homework etc I'll see if your solution works because I still have the files on my computer.

Answer (score 1):

why no just do this?

```
$("div.hideMe").hide();
```

( side note, this could also easily be done with css if they all share a common css file)

Comment: This was similar to what I was trying to do. When I try to do something like this I get `Type Error: $(...).hide() is undefined.` in Firebug.